# openCV undistortPoints matrix operand is an empty matrix

Tags: python, opencv, stereo-3d

I am trying to construct a stereo vision charuco pose detection. I have been able to stereoCalibrate and I have my intrinsic matrices from both cameras. for sake of development ease I am using the same calibration parameters for both cameras (they are exactly the same and mounted together about 20 cm apart horizontally)
the code block below is what I have been able to put together so far that should estimate the pose (x,y,z) euclidian coordinates in the world space of the detected marker.

```
(retStereo, L_intrinsics, L_distortion, R_intrinsics, R_distortion, R, T, essentialMatrix, fundamentalMatrix) = context.scene.calibration_data

        codec = 0x47504A4D # MJPG
        cap_right = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cap_right.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, codec)
        cap_left =  cv2.VideoCapture(1)
        cap_left.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, codec)

        while(cap_right.isOpened() and cap_left.isOpened()):
            succes_right, frame_right = cap_right.read()
            succes_left, frame_left = cap_left.read()

            cornersR, idsR, rejected_img_pointsR = aruco.detectMarkers(frame_right, ARUCO_DICT, parameters=ARUCO_PARAMETERS, cameraMatrix=context.scene.cameraMatrix, distCoeff=context.scene.distCoeffs)
            cv2.aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame_right,cornersR,idsR)
            if np.all(idsR is not None):
                for i in range(0, len(idsR)):
                    R_rvec, R_tvec, R_markerPoints = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(cornersR[i], context.scene.cal_board_markerLength, context.scene.cameraMatrix, context.scene.distCoeffs) 
                    (R_rvec - R_tvec).any()  # get rid of that nasty numpy value array error
                    aruco.drawAxis(frame_right, context.scene.cameraMatrix, context.scene.distCoeffs, R_rvec, R_tvec, 0.05)  # Draw Axis
                    #convert charuco corners to chessboard corners
                    retR, cornersR, corner_ids_R = cv2.aruco.interpolateCornersCharuco(cornersR, idsR, frame_right, CHARUCO_BOARD)

            cornersL, idsL, rejected_img_pointsL = aruco.detectMarkers(frame_left, ARUCO_DICT, parameters=ARUCO_PARAMETERS, cameraMatrix=context.scene.cameraMatrix, distCoeff=context.scene.distCoeffs)
            cv2.aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame_left,cornersL,idsL)
            if np.all(idsL is not None):
                for i in range(0, len(idsL)):
                    L_rvec, L_tvec, L_markerPoints = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(cornersL[i], context.scene.cal_board_markerLength, context.scene.cameraMatrix, context.scene.distCoeffs) 
                    (L_rvec - L_tvec).any()  # get rid of that nasty numpy value array error
                    aruco.drawAxis(frame_left, context.scene.cameraMatrix, context.scene.distCoeffs, L_rvec, L_tvec, 0.05)  # Draw Axis
                    #convert charuco corners to chessboard corners
                    retL, cornersL, corner_ids_L = cv2.aruco.interpolateCornersCharuco(cornersL, idsL, frame_left, CHARUCO_BOARD)

            if np.all(idsL is not None) and np.all(idsR is not None):
                mtx1 = np.array(L_intrinsics)
                mtx2 = np.array(R_intrinsics)
                print(mtx1, mtx2)
                dist1 = L_distortion
                dist2 = R_distortion
                projMat1 = mtx1 @ cv2.hconcat([np.eye(3), np.zeros((3,1))]) # Cam1 is the origin
                projMat2 = mtx2 @ cv2.hconcat([R, T]) # R, T from stereoCalibrate
                
                # points1 is a (N, 1, 2) float32 from cornerSubPix
                points1u = cv2.undistortPoints(cornersR, mtx1, dist1, None, mtx1)
                points2u = cv2.undistortPoints(cornersL, mtx2, dist2, None, mtx2)

                points4d = cv2.triangulatePoints(projMat1, projMat2, points1u, points2u)
                points3d = (points4d[:3, :]/points4d[3, :]).T
                print(points3d)
```

I show the marker in each camera's view independently and that works but when the marker is in the field of view for both simultaneously undistortPoints throws this error at me

```
    points1u = cv2.undistortPoints(cornersR, mtx1, dist1, None, mtx1)
    cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-q0nmoxxv\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix_expressions.cpp:24: 
    error: (-5:Bad argument) Matrix operand is an empty matrix. in function 'cv::checkOperandsExist'
```

here are the mtx1 and mtx2 intrinsics from calibrateCameraCharuco for each camera

```
[[3.34162537e+03 0.00000000e+00 2.03190826e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 3.34045368e+03 1.12097255e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]
```

I'm only showing one because they are the same for each camera (cameras are identical and for dev purposes, I'm using the same images for both). I tried np.array() to covert but still the same issue.

any thoughts?

Comment: The 5th argument of `undistortPoints()`  is rectification transformation matrix (3x3 rotation matrix), however you are using the intrinsic matrix there. https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga55c716492470bfe86b0ee9bf3a1f0f7e

Comment: "Matrix operand is an empty matrix", could you check cornersR? It is seems the matrix is missing? Could you also cast to float32 just to be sure .astype(np.float32)

Comment: @GabrielA. thank you! so it seems that the problem is coming from cv2.aruco.interpolateCornersCharuco because when i print(cornersR/L) before interpolateCornersCharuco the object contains the corner data, however after executing the method the corners objects become 'None'

Comment: *UPDATE* I got it to work! now to the lab to investigate. I converted video stream to gray via cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY). also and more importantly interpolateCornersCharuco works and returns corners when there are at least 2 aruco markers in view!  i will post working code example soon when i refine things a bit. there is some slight jitter, any suggestions on how that can be refined?

Comment: @sebasth when would i use stereoRectify?

Comment: As explained in `undistortPoints()` documentation, when correct R and P are provided the function will return points as rectified image coordinates (u', v'). If that is what you want, you can calculate R and P for both cameras using `stereoRectify()` in the beginning.