# python opencv undistortPoints and triangulatePoints gives weird results

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, triangulation

I have a two camera setup, I use opencv triangulation to get 3d coordinates of an object that is seen from both cameras, but I get some weird results.

Here are the steps I take:

1. First I use cv2.calibrateCamera for both cameras to get intrinsic matrices and distortion coefficients:

```
_, left_camera_intrinsic_matrix, left_camera_distortion_coefficients, _, _ = cv2.calibrateCamera(
obj_points_left, img_points_left, left_shape, None, None)

_, right_camera_intrinsic_matrix, right_camera_distortion_coefficients, _, _ = cv2.calibrateCamera(
obj_points_right, img_points_right, right_shape, None, None)
```

2. Next, I find the left camera's rotation and position relative to the right camera with cv2.stereoCalibrate

```
_, _, _, _, _, rot, trans, _, _ = cv2.stereoCalibrate(obj_points, img_points_left,
                                                      img_points_right, left_camera_intrinsic_matrix,
                                                      left_camera_distortion_coefficients,
                                                      right_camera_intrinsic_matrix,
                                                      right_camera_distortion_coefficients,
                                                      left_shape)
left_camera_rotation, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(rot)
left_camera_position = trans
```

3. I get rectified projection matrices with cv2.stereoRectify

```
right_camera_position = (0, 0, 0)
right_camera_rotation = (0, 0, 0)

right_projection_matrix, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(right_camera_rotation)
right_projection_matrix = np.hstack(
    (right_projection_matrix, np.array(right_camera_position).reshape(-1, 1)))

left_projection_matrix = np.hstack((rot, left_camera_position.reshape(-1, 1)))

_, _, rectified_right_prj_mtx, rectified_left_prj_mtx, _, _, _ = \
    cv2.stereoRectify(right_camera_intrinsic_matrix, right_camera_distortion_coefficients,
                      left_camera_intrinsic_matrix,
                      left_camera_distortion_coefficients, left_shape, rot,
                      left_camera_position)
```

4. Finally for each frame of video I use cv2.undistortPoints and cv2.triangulatePoints to get 3d coordinates

```
right = cv2.undistortPoints(right_points, right_camera_intrinsic_matrix,
                            right_camera_distortion_coefficients, rectified_right_prj_mtx)
left = cv2.undistortPoints(left_points, left_camera_intrinsic_matrix,
                           left_camera_distortion_coefficients, rectified_left_prj_mtx)

# find 3d points through triangulation
homogeneous_points = \
    cv2.triangulatePoints(right_projection_matrix, left_projection_matrix, right, left)
points_3d = cv2.convertPointsFromHomogeneous(homogeneous_points.T)
```

This works almost well but has some issues.

Here is an example GIF where I moved a chessboard (6x4) towards the right camera and then back.
[example GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09vHM.gif)

#### So my questions are:

- How come the chessboard appears curved (my cameras have some distortion but isn't cv2.undistortPoints supposed to take care of that?)?
- What is causing the apparent size of the chessboard to change? Perspective distortion can't cause so much change, can it?
- Are there any fundamental flaws in my steps here?

Some additional notes:

- I use separate images for both cameras for cv2.calibrateCamera (around 60 for each at different angles and distances). For cv2.stereoCalibrate also I use around 60 pictures although I found that only a couple works just as well
- For this example the cameras were at a 50ish degree angle, but I've tried it in many other ways too and the curving of the board and apparent size change always happen (except when I move the chessboard parallel to one of the cameras, then size change is quite minimal, the board is still curved though)
- The cameras are identical and capture same resolution

So far I've tried (these did not help, some made worse):

- using cv.2stereoRectifyUncalibrated instead of cv2.stereoRectify
- using different images for calibration
- undistorting images and not using cv2.undistortPoints

Comment: Did you check the results of cv2.calibrateCamera for example by undistorting and visually checking sample images?

Comment: Did you find this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66370670/2393191

Comment: Not sure whether it is right to use stereoRectify results on triangulatePoints function. Are the undistorted left and right points somehow related to rectify-result?

Comment: @Micka Thank you for the comments!
yes, I checked cv2.calibrateCamera results by undistorting sample images. worked perfect.
I have stumbled upon that stackoverflow question yes, tried all the ideas, sadly did not change anything.
As for the stereoRectify usage, you might be right. I tried without it (so pass only three arguments to cv2.undistortPoints). The code worked but still got the same results, so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: here they suggest to not use stereoRectify in the beginning: https://answers.opencv.org/question/178099/opencv-triangulatepoints-and-stereorectify-relation/ I think currently you are mixing rectified and non-rectified things quite strongly.

Answer (score 0):

*SOLVED*
As also stated by user Micka, the stereoRectify was a bit wrong and in fact not needed.
Projection matrices can be obtained as:

```
right_camera_position = (0, 0, 0)
right_camera_rotation = (0, 0, 0)

right_projection_matrix, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(right_camera_rotation)
right_projection_matrix = np.hstack(
    (right_projection_matrix, np.array(right_camera_position).reshape(-1, 1)))

.......

rpe, _, _, _, _, rot, trans, _, _ = \
    cv2.stereoCalibrate(obj_points, img_points_left, img_points_right, left_intrinsic_matrix,
                        left_camera_distortion_coefficients, right_intrinsic_matrix,
                        right_camera_distortion_coefficients, right_shape)

left_camera_rotation, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(rot)
left_camera_position = trans

# set left camera projection matrix
left_projection_matrix = np.hstack((rot, left_camera_position.reshape(-1, 1)))
```

Just to help out some beginners like myself in the future, I combined my working code to a single file and put it on github. Some example code like this would probably have saved me like 40 hours of debugging and confusion, so I really hope it helps someone in the future.

[opencv-triangulation-example on github](https://github.com/peetermrn/opencv-triangulation-example)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).